# GNOME desktop randomly restarts after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome, upgrade, desktop-environments, restart, 19.10

On **Ubuntu 19.10** installed on the laptop by upgrading from **CLI**, the **GNOME desktop** has started to randomly restart. It happens sometimes after a few minutes, sometimes after hours. It is very annoying because all the time I lost unsaved works.

*Sidenote: the system was upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10 to 19.04, every time from CLI and it never showed an issue.*